# Unresolved import in VSCode for Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Trying to run a flask hello world program

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0..0.')
```

The Error:

```
unresolved import 'flask'
```

I have done **Ctrl-Shift-P** to select a Python interpreter but that did not seem to work.

The pip list seems to show flask so I am not sure why my import is not working.

```
Package       Version   
------------- ----------
appdirs       1.4.3     
CacheControl  0.12.6    
certifi       2019.11.28
chardet       3.0.4     
click         7.1.2     
colorama      0.4.3     
contextlib2   0.6.0     
distlib       0.3.0     
distro        1.4.0     
Flask         1.1.2     
html5lib      1.0.1     
idna          2.8       
ipaddr        2.2.0     
itsdangerous  1.1.0     
Jinja2        2.11.3    
lockfile      0.12.2    
MarkupSafe    1.1.1     
msgpack       0.6.2     
packaging     20.3      
pep517        0.8.2     
pip           20.0.2    
pkg-resources 0.0.0     
progress      1.5       
pyparsing     2.4.6     
python-dotenv 0.15.0    
pytoml        0.1.21    
requests      2.22.0    
retrying      1.3.3     
setuptools    44.0.0    
six           1.14.0    
urllib3       1.25.8    
webencodings  0.5.1     
Werkzeug      1.0.1     
wheel         0.34.2
```

These are the settings from pyenv.cfg

```
home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.9.2.final.0
virtualenv = 20.0.17
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3.9
```

Comment: what do you get when you do pip install flask ?

Comment: I get:
`Requirement already satisfied: flask in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.1.2)`

Comment: and what do you see in you launch.json file?

Comment: These are my configurations:
`    
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
`

Comment: From settings.json:
`"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3.9"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the python environment used by the current VS Code terminal is different from the python displayed in the lower left corner of VS Code.

When using the "`Jedi`" language service, it does not show the problems in the code by default, and when using "`Microsoft`" or "`Pylance`" as the language service, VS Code will show the problems in the code.

Please use "`python --version`" to check the current python version used in VS Code. If it is different, please use Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal.

Check: (`pip show flask`)

[image]

before:

[image]

after:

[image]

```
"python.languageServer": "Microsoft",
```

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
in settings.json add this line:

```
"python.languageServer": "Jedi"
```